# How is union find quadratic algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

In this implementation of Quick Find algorithm, Constructor takes `N` steps so does `union()`.

The instructor said that `union` is too expensive as it takes `N^2` to process sequence of `N` `union` commands on `N` objects, **How can `union` be quadratic when it accesses array elements one at a time?**

```
public class QuickFind
{
    private int[] id;

    public QuickFind(int N) {
        id = new int[N];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            id[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public boolean connected(int p, int q) {
        return id[p] == id[q];
    }

    public void union(int p, int q) {
        int pid = id[p];
        int qid = id[q];

        for (int i=0; i<id.length; i++)
            if (id[i] == pid)
                id[i] = qid;
    }
}
```

Comment: He's saying a sequence of N union operations takes quadratic time, not a single invocation.

Comment: Suppose you create a new `QuickFind` datastructe with input of size `n`. Initially, there are `n` connected components, each of size 1. If you want, for example, to unify all components into single one, you have to call `union` operation `n-1` times. As each of the  union call takes O(n), you end up with complexity O(n^2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each invocation of `union` method requires you iterate over the `id` array, which takes `O(n)` time. If you invoke `union` method `n` times, then the time required is `n*O(n) = O(n^2)`.

You can improve time complexity of `union` method to `O(1)`, by making the time complexity of connected method higher, probably `O(log n)`, but this is just one time operation. I believe that your text book explain this in details.

Comment: You can have O(α(n)) for union and find-root, by using path compression and union-by-rank

Answer (score 2):

`Union` operation for **Quick Find** is quadratic `O(n^2)` for `n` operations, because each operation takes `O(n)` time, as is easy to notice in for loop inside `union(int p, int q)`

```
    for (int i=0; i<id.length; i++)
```

Notice that the algorithm is called **Quick Find**, as each find (`connected(int p, int q)`) operation takes constant time. However for this algorithm you end up paying in `union` operation, as mentioned in your question.

There is another algorithm **Quick Union**, which improves time for `union` operation. But then `find` doesn't remain `O(1)` (but better than linear time).